# Python count max character in a string?

Tags: python

I am trying to find the max character count in a string using loop. So far, this is the code i have written :-

```
def max_char_count(string):
    max_char = ''
    max_count = 0
    for char in string:
        count = string.count(char)
        if count > max_count:
            max_count = count
            max_char = char
    return max_char

print(max_char_count('apple hellooo'))
```

But the issue i am running into is even though there are 3 l and 3 o. I am only getting the output as l. How can i adjust the code to show the right count for the characters? Thank you.

Comment: In the event of a tie do you want to produce the list of all the characters that are tied for the maximum?  If so you need to keep a list of characters rather than a single `max_char`.

Comment: @Samwise Yes, that is right. I would like to show both. Oh okay. so max_char should be a list.

Comment: FWIW a much easier approach is to use `collections.Counter`.  `c = collections.Counter("apple hellooo")`; `print([k for k, v in c.items() if v == max(c.values())])`

Comment: @Samwise Although a good approach. I am trying to use purely loops and data types and no module.

Comment: @Samwise also `m = max(c.values())` and then use that in the listcomp for O(n) instead of n^2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is inefficient because you need to iterate over the whole string to compute `string.count(char)` while you iterate over the entire string anyway, which gives a time complexity of O(n^2)

Instead, I suggest you calculate the counts of each character *once* looping through the string, and then select the one(s) with the maximum count.

```
def max_char_count(string):
    ret = []
    counter = dict() # create an empty dict to store the character counts
    # Itrate over the string once to count the characters
    # N iterations
    for char in string:
        # `.get()` returns the given default value (0) if the `char` key doesn't exist
        # If it does, it returns the value for that key
        # Then you increment it
        counter[char] = counter.get(char, 0) + 1 

    # Find the max value 
    # (another loop over the dict, worst-case N iterations)
    max_count = max(counter.values())    
    
    # Iterate over the dict one last time to get the keys that have a value == max_count
    # Again, worst-case N iterations
    for char, count in counter.items():
        if count == max_count:
            ret.append((char, count))

    return ret
```

Now, `print(max_char_count('apple hellooo'))` returns `[('o', 3), ('l', 3)]`

If you don't want to reinvent the counting wheel, use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead. `counter = collections.Counter(string)`

Since we have three loops and none of them are nested loops, we get a time complexity of O(3*n) (or just O(n))

Comment: What if the string is `string = 'apple is fruit but applepie is desert`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary of characters to count the occurrences, then find the largest count and return all keys that have that count. The fromkeys() constructor will allow you to initialize the letter counts to zero thus making the counting loop much simpler. Selecting the letters with the maximum count can be done using a list comprehension.

This will compute the result in very few lines of code:

```
string    = 'apple hellooo'

counts    = dict.fromkeys(string,0)  # initialize counts to zero
for c in string: counts[c] += 1      # compute characters counts
max_count = max(counts.values())     # find maximum count
result    = [c for c,n in counts.items() if n==max_count] # matching characters

print(result)
['o', 'l']
```